# Can VLC stream a YouTube video?

Tags: video, streaming, youtube, vlc-media-player

Is it possible to stream a particular YouTube video's content with VLC?

The scenario is that you could paste a YouTube URL into a VLC dialog, and then have VLC stream the video as if it were a local media file.

Current version - when trying to open a file or network stream results in

> VLC can't recognize the input's format:
>   The format of 'http://www.youtube.com/v/foo' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.

Any existing features in VLC, or workarounds that you know of to accomplish this streaming idea?

Comment: did u try it? alot of sites can stream to vlc just haven't tried youtube

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If you grab the actual video stream file (using a youtube downloader site, or firefox add-in), and pasting the URL into VLC, it will stream/play the file.

I do this all the time from an OS that doesn't support Flash (easily), but does support VLC & Firefox.

Comment: Judging by your avatar is this OS.... FreeBSD? ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can absolutely download and play YouTube videos with VLC.

1. Copy your video ID from the youtube URL. In this case I am using: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEiat9O74ms`
2. I will use the following URL to view your video:
   `http://www.youtube.com/embed/BEiat9O74ms` Where `BEiat9074ms` is the video ID of the video you want to watch.
3. In VLC, under the Media menu, select "Open Network Stream" and paste the URL from step 2. into the network URL:
4. Enjoy your YouTube video in VLC.

Comment: This works for me, very cool. Do you know if it's possible choose playback resolution? Or does it just default to the highest?

Comment: The same parameters for a normal video should apply according to the documentation. There is also another question which has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582336/force-youtube-embed-to-start-in-720p

Comment: With some live streamings like [this one of FreeCodeCamp](https://www.youtube.com/freecodecamp/live) return `adaptive demux: Encountered discontinuity` and then `ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you pasting a YouTube URL into VLC? You use your web browser to display web pages, which in turn loads an instance of Adobe Flash which **then retrieves a different URL to the video**.

I used a YouTube URL retrieval service to try and get the FLV, and I put it into VLC and it came up with an error.

You can investigate the log files and see if it is possible to investigate further. It may be that YouTube does some `User-Agent` filtering, and you will need to have VLC masquarade as a web browser/Adobe Flash to retrieve the stream.

Comment: The question is centered more around whether VLC might perform some of that URL bait and switch automatically on the user's behalf.

Comment: I know it is, I'm pointing out that it doesn't.

Comment: The REALLY important point is that it ONLY plays the URL entered, not the Google / YouTube bait and switch that results in embedded advertisements in the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it , with version 1.1.0. Just put the URl in Network tab

Comment: Nope. In 1.1.12: `The format of 'http://www.youtube.com/v/k_oTQd93eRI' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.` The log says `Compressed SWF format not supported`. Maybe codecs are missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! URL looks something like this:

http://o-o.preferred.ams03g05.v22.lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=MvzQEOUAqgE&sparams=cp,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&fexp=917000,914057,900504,913540,907217,907335,921602,919306,919316,912804,913542,919324,912706&ms=au&itag=22&ip=217.0.0.0&signature=D48AAC2615B0C914C1C01D315BEEC98155E83973.077998BD7AA95D841B837CF5BB7A05FBD0F818BB&sver=3&mt=1339246511&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1339271656&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hSTlJST19KUENOMl9KTFNHOmk3NXkyRGRCN0ZD&id=7eb8b9ded2a7eff9&title=%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%20%E2%84%9673

You need to start download a video and then copy download link!

Comment: Where does one copy the download link?

Comment: Easy  Youtube video downloader 6.1, but also I was able to watch just throught http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=fri53tKn7_k and it was 720p

Answer (score 0):

Is similar to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1412778/500826). Install [Streamlink](https://streamlink.github.io/):

```
sudo -H pip install streamlink
```

Then send the stream to `vlc --fullscreen`:

```
streamlink --player="vlc --fullscreen" "https://www.youtube.com/freecodecamp/live" best
```

Personally what I was needing was just the audio, `cvlc --no-video`.

To save bandwidth you could use `worst` instead of `best`.